# Area between $1$ and $2$ of $x^2$ and $x^{1/2}$ using integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration, area

I need to find the area between $x = 1, x = 2$, between the functions $x^2$ and $x^{1/2}$. Please show all steps so I can get a better understanding! Thank you

Comment: You didn't do anything yourself?

Comment: I don't know how to add a picture, I've done it I just can't figure out how to simplify at the end theres a fraction causing me an issue, in my notes I have 8/3 - 4sqrt2/3 + 1/3 and I want to know how the 4sqrt2/3 comes from

Answer (score 4):

$$\int_1^2\left(x^2-\sqrt x\right)dx=\left.\left(\frac13x^3-\frac23x^{3/2}\right)\right|_1^2=...?$$

Comment: The part I don't understand is how 2/3x^2/3 becomes 4 squareroot of 2 on 3 I have it in my notes but I don't understand how I got this before lol it's for the area of the second half since there is an intersection

Comment: I don't understand you, @andrea. All I can do is show to you $$\left.\left(\frac13x^3-\frac23x^{3/2}\right)\right|_1^2=\frac13(8-1)-\frac23(2\sqrt2-1)=\frac{8-4\sqrt2}3+\frac13$$

Comment: @Timbuc you are right! That is the correct answer, the step I don't get is when your before last step becomes the last step I get confused with the square root and how that happens

Comment: @Andrea Note that $\sqrt x = x^{\frac12}$ and $\int_a^b x^k = \left. \frac1{k+1} x^{k+1} \right|_a^b$ for all $k\ne -1$.

Comment: @Andrea:for **any** $\;-1\neq n\in\Bbb R\;$ , we have that $$\int x^n\;dx=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+C$$ so in this case $$\int\sqrt x\;dx=\int x^{1/2}\,dx=\frac{x^{1/2+1}}{1/2+1}=\frac23x^{3/2}=\frac23x\sqrt x$$

Comment: Alright thanks I didn't know the last part 2/3x√x. Very helpful thanks so much! @Timbuc